# Serverless my custom authorizer is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have the following serverless.yaml:

```
    getSth: 
        handler: src/handlers/getSth.getSth
        events:
            - http:
                path: getSth
                method: get
                cors: true
                private: true
                authorizer: authorizerFunc
    authorizerFunc:
        handler: src/handlers/authorizer.authorizer
```

getSth handler:

```
    module.exports.getSth = async (event, context) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: "nice you can call this});
    }
    return response;
    }
```

authorizerFunc:

```
    module.exports.authorizer = async (event, context) => {
         console.log('i will fail your authorization');
         let response = {
         isAuthorized: false,
         context: {
           stringKey: "value",
           numberKey: 1,
           booleanKey: true,
           arrayKey: ["value1", "value2"],
           mapKey: { value1: "value2" },
    },
  };
  return response;
}
```

That results in getting respons 200 in spite of the fact authorizer should not allow to execute that getSth function. Also console log 'I will fail your authorization' is not logged.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi, do you have the ability to share the CloudWatch logs for `getSth` and `authorizerFunc`?

Comment: From your `yaml` it seems you are deploying a REST Api (ie API Gateway V1) but that form of authorizer functions is for HTTP Api (ie API Gateway V2). For REST Apis, your authorizer lambda has to return an IAM policy. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html vs https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/introducing-iam-and-lambda-authorizers-for-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/

Comment: And did you check in the AWS console, that the authorizer is actually attached to your function?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to analyse your code and find several points where you can start digging.

## Private functions

The key `private: true` actually makes API Gateway require an API key. I did now not try myself but perhaps `private: true` and an authorizer do not go together.

Strange still that you are able to call the function then. How do you call the function? From the CLI or through API Gateway and an API testing tool such as Postman or Insomnia?

## Authorizer Configuration

Your authorizer configuration is definitely correct. We do have the very same setup in our code.

## Authorizer Events

An authorizer function gets an `APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent` in and should reply with a `APIGatewayAuthorizerResult`. The latter looks closely like an IAM statement and we do not use the field `isAuthorized: false` as per your example. I do not understand where this field is coming from. Our result to allow a request looks more or less like the following:

```json
{
  "principalId": "<our auth0 user-id>",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }]
  }
}
```

Note how the field `principalId` refers to the username we get from our identity provider (Auth0). And in reality looks something like this: `auth0|6f84a3z162c72d0d0d000a00`.

Further, we can allow or deny the function call via the `Effect` field which can hold the values `Allow` or `Deny`.

Finally, you can specify which resource the caller is permitted to call. For simplicity of this answer I put `*` there. Of course in the real world you can pull the ARN of the called function from the event and context and pass that into the policy document.

## Opinion

We also had a hard way of figuring this out via documentation from AWS. Of course for AWS the preferred integration would be via AWS Cognito (which I also do prefer due to the more streamlined integration. We benefited quite a bit form the use of TypeScript here which we use to enforce types in and out of our Serverless functions. This way it was rather easy to figure out how the response needs to look like.

## Background

We use the custom authorizer integration to allow a user base already existing in Auth0 consume our Serverless based APIs via application clients or single page applications.