# Where to find type definitions (in particular for Lambda) in AWS SDK 2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Many examples for AWS Lambda on the Internet refer to the old v1.0 of the SDK, which shipped in the `aws-lambda` package. The newer v2.0 SDK is in the `@aws-sdk` namespace on npmjs and split into smaller packages.

With the v2.0 packages, I am finding it difficult to find even essential type definitions, like for the events that an AWS Lambda function receives from EventBridge or for Authorization requests.

For the authorization use-case, I found example payloads in the [AWS SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html), but again, no types. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714383/serverless-my-custom-authorizer-is-not-working) mentions `APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent` and `APIGatewayAuthorizerResult` from the v1.0 packages. Where would I find these in v2.0? What is the best way to search for these types? Github search turns out to be very tedious.